# Calculate temperature rise on an inductor in a switching-mode power supply

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, ltspice, power-dissipation

I'm a little bit confused about this matter. I've got a switching-mode battery charger (basically, a power supply) based on the LT3650. I want to know how much the inductor temperature is going to rise because a previous design had it going very hot. The selected inductor was a Bourns SRR1280-330M (33µH). I've downloaded the LTSpice simulation for the chip and I'm doing the following measurements:

```
.MEAS L2_POWER RMS V(LNET1,LNET2)*I(L2) TRIG v(out) VAL=6 TARG v(out) VAL=7
.MEAS L2_AVG AVG V(LNET1,LNET2)*I(L2) TRIG v(out) VAL=6 TARG v(out) VAL=7
.MEAS L2_P2P PP I(L2) TRIG v(out) VAL=6 TARG v(out) VAL=7
```

LNET1 and LNET2 are the two inductor nodes, and v(out)=6 to 7 is the significant range of battery charging voltage. I guess the rest of the model is not relevant since we're only interested in the inductor.

I'm getting:

```
l2_power: RMS(v(lnet1,lnet2)*i(l2))=18.6632 FROM 0.000174199 TO 0.000645851
l2_avg: AVG(v(lnet1,lnet2)*i(l2))=0.074568 FROM 0.000174199 TO 0.000645851
l2_p2p: PP(i(l2))=0.748642 FROM 0.000174199 TO 0.000645851
    * (FROM/TO is the time range the measurements were taken from)
```

I don't know what value to take as power dissipation; I understand that inductors are not resistors and things get complicated with them. My instincts tell me to use the RMS power value (l2_power), but 18 watts sounds like a lot, and doesn't seem to change no matter what inductor I choose (different µH or DCR). The average value (74mW) sounds too little for the temperature rise I've observed. Peak-to-peak was just for the kicks.

I know I have a total current of 2 amps, and the ripple current is about 25% of that. Now, the inductor manufacturer mentions a temperature rise that depends only of the RMS current (not the power), and it's usually 40°C times Irms(max).

The question is: should I use the manufacturer calculations as the base for temperature rise expectations (excluding PCB dissipation)? If I pass half the Irms(max), should I expect a 20°C temperature rise? Otherwise, what method should I use to estimate that using LTSpice?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us your simulation schematic?  I downloaded the example from Analog Device's website and changed the inductor to Bourns SRR1280-330M, but I got AVG(v(n002,n003)*i(L1))=**0.218608** FROM 0.000827371 TO 0.00130489. (this is close to the expected power dissipation of a 0.057 Ohm resistor carrying 2A).

Comment: So you say AVG is the right function for calculating the power dissipation? What about the negative values? I'm using the exact simulation schematic from AD, but with RMS instead of AVG. Somehow AVG doesn't sound right to me. For instance, an inductor with zero DC bias would show a zero AVG(P) no matter what the AC content is, but it should dissipate something!

Comment: @GuillermoPrandi a zero AVG(P) roughly means that current has to flow opposite to the voltage half of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) is only valid for current in or voltage across a purely resistive load. For power dissipated by a reactive component you should calculate the average of all the instantaneous power values, as this takes into account where the power goes during each cycle.

An inductor stores and releases magnetic energy as the current through it increases and decreases, causing the voltage across it to swing positive and negative. Over a full cycle the total 'negative' energy coming out of a pure inductor should equal the 'positive' energy going in, so the overall power loss is zero. RMS calculations take the individual square roots of squared current and voltage components, loosing the sign and producing an *apparent* power loss which doesn't actually exist. Calculating instantaneous power *first* and then averaging the results produces the correct value.

Real inductors have series resistance in the windings and parallel resistance in the core, which turns some of the energy into heat. Usually the series component dominates, so if current ripple is low then simply multiplying the average inductor current by its series resistance can provide a fairly accurate measure of power loss.

Once you know the power loss you can then calculate temperature rise using the '[thermal resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_resistance)' (which is analogous to resistance in an electrical circuit, but with power as 'current' and temperature difference as 'voltage') of the inductor and what it is heat-sinked to.

Note that total thermal resistance depends on how the component is mounted, PCB copper area, air circulation etc. If these figures are not available then you may have to make some physical temperature measurements to characterize them. It might be more convenient to pass a pure DC current through the inductor while doing this, because then the power calculation is much simpler because the inductance has no effect.